# Platform SDK Deployment in C#

Tags: c#, .net, deployment

I was reading the Platform SDK samples, and the examples are in VB.NET.  I use C# so I was wondering, how can I replicate this line in C#?

```
Set   Installer   =   CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

Type InstallerType;
object Installer;

InstallerType= Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WindowsInstaller.Installer");
Installer= Activator.CreateInstance(InstallerType);
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks like VB6/VBScript, not VB.NET :) But I might be wrong.

Options are:

1. Look for the [.NET framework equivalent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx) of the WindowsInstaller.Installer object and use that.
2. Use [Activator.CreateInstance()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx). But don't expect a strongly-typed response.
3. Add a reference to the WindowsInstaller.Installer COM object and VS will generate a strongly-typed interop which will allow you to create an instance in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Go to add reference, select COM tab and select "WindowsInstaller". ('Interop.WindowsInstaller')

```
Add : using WindowsInstaller;

Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WindowsInstaller.Installer");
Installer msi = (Installer)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

//ur code: -
foreach (string productcode in msi.Products)
{
//ur code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's VBScript I think.

You'd be better off searching for whatever you're trying to do within the .NET framework.  It has a rich installer library that should make it easy.  Don't just try to use some COM object because that's what you found.  Work in the framework you're in.